# Calling fnparse to parse a string?

Tags: clojure

I've been trying out [fnparse](http://github.com/joshua-choi/fnparse/tree/3.%CE%B1.3) library written by Joshua Choi in Clojure and I'm having difficulties trying to work out how to call the rules on the text that I want to parse. I've been experimenting with [cat](http://github.com/joshua-choi/fnparse/blob/3.%CE%B1.3/src/edu/arizona/fnparse/cat.clj) which is part of the new release. Lets take the [example code](http://github.com/joshua-choi/fnparse/blob/3.%CE%B1.3/src/edu/arizona/fnparse/math.clj) listed. Could anyone give me some ideas how I could call the  rule on an expression?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for trying out FnParse 3.

In general, you use the `edu.arizona.fnparse/match` form (as well as the complementary `find`, `substitute`, and `substitute-1` forms) to use the rules that you create. Check their documentation strings.

Sorry about the confusion—I should have added an example of `match` in `math.clj`—but take a look at the bottom of [the sample Clojure parser](http://github.com/joshua-choi/fnparse/blob/3.%CE%B1.3/src/edu/arizona/fnparse/clojure.clj). Even though the Clojure parser uses FnParse Hound, `match` works the same way in both Cat and Hound.